# How to return final result using recursion in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on nodejs. Currently I'm doing the recursive part of my work.

In **prodHelper.js**

```
product: (data, totalUser) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        // data = {total: 5, order: 6, status: active} -> As a dynamic data
        let number = 1
        let res = await prodHelper.groupProduct(data, totalUser, number)
        console.log('RESULT', res) // undefined
    })
}
groupProduct: (data, totalUser, number) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let result
        if (data.total < totalUser) {
            result = true
        } else {
            let nextNumber = number;
            if (number < totalUser) {
                nextNumber = nextNumber + 1
            } else if (number == totalUser) {
                nextNumber = number - totalUser
            }
            if (nextNumber >= 0 && nextNumber < totalUser) {
                await prodHelper.groupProduct(data, totalUser, nextNumber)
            } 
        }
        return resolve(result)
    })
}
```

I have run my code recursively successfully. But my problem here is when I call `product` function it waits for `groupProduct` function to run and return the result. But the `groupProduct` function returns the results of the first run, not waiting for the results of the recursive run.

It will return `undefined`, because it does not wait for recursion. Is there a way for it to wait for the recursion to finish and then return `resolve(result)`.

I tried that. But it returns `HTTP status code 503` :

```
groupProduct: (data, totalUser, number) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let result
        if (data.total < totalUser) {
            result = true
        } else {
            let nextNumber = number;
            if (number < totalUser) {
                nextNumber = nextNumber + 1
            } else if (number == totalUser) {
                nextNumber = number - totalUser
            }
            if (nextNumber >= 0 && nextNumber < totalUser) {
                await prodHelper.groupProduct(data, totalUser, nextNumber)
            } 
        }
        if (result) {
            return resolve(result) //error 503 : Service Unavailable
        }
    })
}
```

I am new to nodejs language so this is giving me a hard time. Can anyone give me any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please how are you calling `product` function, with what parameters basically?

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: "*returns the results of the first run, not waiting for the results of the recursive run.*" - oh it does wait, you're just not doing anything with the `await`ed return value of the recursive call. After the line of the recursive call, `result` simply still is `undefined`.

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but is there a reason not represented in your sample code that this needs to use promises/be async?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor call `product` function i use api. I knew someone would ask, so I wrote an example `// data = {total: 5, order: 6, status: active} -> As a dynamic data`

Comment: @Bergi Actually, I've just switched to nodejs from php. I used `promise` to wait. And inside the if `data.total < totalUser` function I also tried returning `result resolve(true) ` but still no okay. I'm really stuck

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous here so there's no reason to use promises at all.

Comment: `await prodHelper.groupProduct(data, totalUser, nextNumber)` should be this `result = await prodHelper.groupProduct(data, totalUser, nextNumber)`

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Great answer. Please create a separate answer. I will vote for your answer

Comment: @Miedkes Recursion doesn't really work different than in PHP. Making the recursive call and awaiting it are one thing, returning its result is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @Bergi, in the `groupProduct` function, the statement:

```
await prodHelper.groupProduct(data, totalUser, nextNumber)
```

should be

```
result = await prodHelper.groupProduct(data, totalUser, nextNumber)
```